# generate automatic statement from an excel list to multiple recipient

Tags: excel, automation, excel-formula, vba

when my colleagues go on a meeting or conference that is to be held abroad, they are entitled to a small allowance. Every month, each allowance is calculated and a batch payment is made on excel as follows (Picture)
Out of this list, I am looking for a way to automatically create individual statement (with on or multiple transactions in it) to each staff member on the list.

[image]
Does anyone know where I should start to get to the point where I can automatically generate a bunch of statements to email to each staff member on the list?

The statement should contain:

Full name
PO
Sort code
Account number
Amount in €
Amount in £
Exchange rate
User reference
Possibly a sentence or two at the bottom (payment terms and policy used)

Thanking you in advance for your help.
Abs

Comment: Check it out,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogt3PzeRQgg

Comment: (1) if you read correctly, you would have noted that I wrote "Does anyone know where "i" should start" and not can someone do it for me! (2) I would not use a code without understanding what it does. I suggest you ignore posts you are not prepared to help with.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: the below will only take individual transactions and email it to the user. Pulling together a full statement is probably best done using a user form so you can control what data you want to include. I'd suggest a beginners VBA cours (check w3 schools) to get familiar with the basics, and the below can then be tweaked to do what you're looking for.

Hit `Alt` + `F11` from Excel and then double click on This Worksheet and then paste the following code:

```
Sub sendemails()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim i As Long
i = 7

Dim UserNameCol As String
UserNameCol = "U"

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Do Until Len(Cells(i, UserNameCol).Value) = 0 'will stop when blank cell appears

'Set up all the variables you need for your emails and fill them
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim FullName As String
    Dim PO As String
    Dim SortCode As String
    Dim AccountNum As String
    Dim Euro As String
    Dim Pound As String
    Dim ExchRate As String

'i is the counter to move through the list and the username col is U
    UserName = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Value
    FullName = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Offset(, -19).Value
    SortCode = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Offset(, -16).Value
    AccountNum = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Offset(, -15).Value
    PO = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Offset(, -14).Value
    Euro = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Offset(, -13).Value
    Exchange = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Offset(, -12).Value
    Pound = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Offset(, -11).Value
    ExchRate = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Offset(, -10).Value

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 'this goes here because a new email is needed each time
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail

        'Customise the below as required
        .To = UserName
        .Importance = 1
        .Subject = "Hello"
        .Body = "Full Name: " & FullName & vbCr & _
                    "PO: " & PO & vbCr & _
                    "Sort Code: " & SortCode & vbCr & _
                    "Account Number: " & AccountNum & vbCr & _
                    "Amount Euro: " & Euro & vbCr & _
                    "Amount Pound: " & Pound & vbCr & _
                    "Exchange Rate: " & ExchRate & vbCr & vbCr & _
                    "Thanks for reading."

        'display shows each email before sending
        .Display
        'send sends email automatically
        '.Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    i = i + 1

Loop

'destroy outlook when finished processing all mails
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I'd try it out on a couple keeping the `.Display` property set and once you're happy it works, comment out `.Display` and uncomment out `.Send` (add or remove the apostrophe at the start of the line as necessary).

Also ensure you have the Microsoft Outlook Object Library enabled (Tools > References > MS Outlook Object Library).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Re-reading I think I've maybe missed the point of the question. This code is intended to take information that is already listed on the spreadsheet and place it into an email. It won't carry out any calculations.

Comment: thank you for your time. I am going through the information you shared to see how I can use it for my purpose. I don't need to carry out calculations. I am going to link this code to a button and go through step by step to make it work. Thank you

Comment: Good shout, it will at the very least send the users a summary of each individual transaction, and I'm sure you can modify it or at least use some of the code to expand and send a complete statement. Give me a shout if you need any clarification on any part of the code.

Comment: The above does not seem to work for me. I introduced a button and linked the formula to it. I also tried to have the user reference as the email subject but it does not work at the minute.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you enabled the MS Object library? Also, please bear in mind this will only email one individual transaction, not a summary.